# F# How to append an element to the end of a list

Tags: f#

How do I append a value to the end of a list?

```
let rec add lst value =
        match lst with
        | [] -> [value]
```

This currently only appends an empty list with the value x. How would I add a value to the end of a list that has elements in already in it?

Answer (score 5):

For simple recursive version use

```
let rec add lst value =
    match lst with
    | [] -> [ value ]
    | h :: t -> h :: add t value
```

Note that this implementation is not tail recursive.

But in pratice use the built in append operator

```
let add lst value = lst @ [ value ]
```

Or the standard function `List.append` which has the arguments in an other order.

```
let add lst value = List.append [ value ] lst
```

Also worth knowingis that append is an expensive function on a singly linked immutable list which create a new copy of the entire list.